# Paypal PHP SDK going from sandbox to live

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Hey guys I followed this tutorial

http://www.sanwebe.com/2014/09/paypal-rest-api-payment-system

I have the paypal sandbox mode working perfect. It's time to launch the site & I want to switch it to live. I've been messing with it for hours and cannot figure out how to direct this to the live mode.

Any help at all will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using [PayPal-PHP-SDK,](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK)

**Step 1:** You need to set the `mode` to `live` to point the SDK to live endpoints. To do that, there are multiple ways:

- sdk_config.ini

  - you need to set this [there](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/sdk_config.ini#L24)
  - [image]
- dynamically using ApiContext

  - you could do that by setting it similar to [this](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/bootstrap.php#L74)
  - [image]

**Step 2:**, Please update the clientId and secret for Live environment, as they are different based on sandbox or live. Visit [PayPal Developer](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps) and check on live select box as shown below:

[image]

These two steps should get you going with the live API endpoint.

Comment: I think I will add a page in https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki explaining about switching to live. This should help developers in future.

Comment: Btw, The Wiki Page had been added to go live : https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Going-Live

Comment: @JayPatel-PayPal I followed these steps (used Live Credentials and used 'live' as mode) but the api it is still routing me to sandbox.api.paypal.com where I see a 401 error. Is there anything required from the PayPal portal?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31006459/paypal-rest-api-end-point-used

Comment: @JayPatel-PayPal - This information needs to be updated. The wiki should specifically mention which directory the sdk_config.ini file should sit. There is one inside the /tests directory, so where is the config coming from out of the box? Your wiki / example also doesn't mention changing the service.EndPoint

Comment: @JayPatel-PayPal -  Looking back through code I notice that inside RestHandler.php there is a call _getEndpoint. This has the sanbox set as default endpoint if there is no config file. So for people using the REST API out of the box there is no chance for them to "go live" without creating a config file or specifying config settings. The wiki doesn't indicate this clearly enough for someone wanting to just switch live.

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment to H Patel, but there's another sdk_config.ini file in the PayPal PHP SDK files which includes an endpoint and mode.

I've noticed I had to change the `service.EndPoint` in this other config file to `https://api.paypal.com`, change the `mode` in both config files to `live`, set the `log.LogLevel` to `INFO`, AND dynamically set the `mode` to `live` in my PHP script. I ALSO changed the `acct1.ClientId` and `acct1.ClientSecret` in both of these config ini files and it seems like maybe I've got it working now.

So it's not a matter of choosing how you want to do it, you have to do all of it and then some beyond what PayPal tells you to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can set manualy to go live without creating config.ini file

Just set in the value you want

```
\PayPal\Core\PayPalConfigManager::getInstance()->addConfigs(['mode' => 'live' /*or "sandbox" */]) ;
```

then set your live Credential id/secret with the live information

```
$credential = new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential($paypal_id, $paypal_secret);
```